# how can I return outerHTML as string in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show an outerHTML of my button in header like the code I added but when I'm using outerHTML , it is creating new element instead of returning string. (***I added those JQuery Codes separately with external JavaScript file but here , site is not allowing me to have two blocks of code , so I put JQuery in my HTML***)

how can I return that as  string ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <title>JQuery Learn</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>This is JQuery Learning</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p class="pclass">Button 1 Click Event</p>
        <button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
    </main>
</body>
</html>




$('#btn1').click(function(e){
 $('header>p').html('this button contains the outerHTML of'+" "+e.currentTarget.outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** do you want to achieve? And how is this related to CSS?

Comment: If you want to show HTML code _as code_, then you need to treat it as _text_, not as HTML. `$('header>p').text(…)`

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to show <button id="btn1>Button 1 </button> in my header tag but it's making new button , I just want that text

Comment: @CBroe correct answer ! that's cool thank you. if you post it as answer I can mark as correct answer

Comment: Feel free to mark Quentin’s answer as the correct; no need to add the same thing a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** returning a string. You've misidentified the cause of the problem.

The `$(...).html()` method takes that string, treats it as HTML, generates DOM elements from it, and inserts the result into the document.

If you want the string inserted as a text node then use the `$(...).text()` method.